# Extract string between a set of multiple limiters with groups

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

As title says, I've a string and I want to extract some data from It.

This is my String:

```
text = "|tab_PRO|1|1|#tRecordType#||0|tab_PRO|";
```

and I want to extract all the data between the pipes: tab_PRO, 1, 1...and so on
.
I've tried:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\|(.*?)\\|");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while(m.find())
    {
        for(int i = 1; i< 10; i++) {
        test = m.group(i); 
        System.out.println(test);
        }
    }
```

and with this i get the first group that's tab_PRO. But i also get an error

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2

Now, probably I didn't understand quite well how the groups works, but I thought that with this I could get the remaining data that I need. I'm not able to understand what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: you can use substring or split method to extract required part of your string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-). Take into account it expects a regex as an argument, and `|` is a reserved regex operand, so you'll need to escape it with a `\`. So, make it two `\` so `\|` won't be interpreted as if you're using an - invalid - escape sequence for the `|` character:

```
String[] parts = text.split("\\|");
```

See it working here: 
https://ideone.com/WibjUm

If you want to go with your regex approach, you'll need to group and capture every repetition of characters after every `|` and restrict them to be anything except `|`, possibly using a regex like `\\|([^\\|]*)`.

In your loop, you iterate over `m.find()` and just use capture group 1 because its the only group every match will have.

```
String text = "|tab_PRO|1|1|#tRecordType#||0|tab_PRO|";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\|([^\\|]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

https://ideone.com/RNjZRQ

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.split()` or `.substring()`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is easier done with `String.split`.

As for your own code, you are unnecessarily using the inner loop, and that's leading to that exception. You only have one group, but the for loop will cause you to query more than one group. Your loop should be as simple as:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\|)(.*?)\\|");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    String test = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

And that prints

```
tab_PRO
1
1
#tRecordType#

0
tab_PRO
```

Note that I had to use a look-behind assertion in your regex.